Why is charge on a conductor stable?
I know that charge inside a conductor should be zero and because of which all the charge of a charged conductor gets evenly distributed on its surface. But my question is:
If we take a charged spherical conductor,lets say of radius$\ R$ and charge $\ Q$, the spherical conductor acts as if the total charge on it is at its center so the charge $\ Q$ develops a potential at the surface of the conductor $\ V =$ $\frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}R}$ where $\epsilon_{0}$ is the absolute permittivity of free space now if we want to bring a small charge $dQ$ from $\infty$ to its surface, it would have to raise its potential energy by $VdQ$ now if, at infinity if we gave it some kinetic energy that totally converts to potential energy at $\ R$, $\ K$ $\ = \frac{mv^{2}}{2}$ $\ = \frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_{m}R}$ after the $\ K$ of the small charge became$\ 0$ at$\ R$ it would want to decrease its potential energy and would start accelerating in the direction of electric field which was due to the charge on the conductor and hence should leave the conductor. Why is this not the case in reality?


read the first 15 pages in this https://archive.org/details/thermodynamicsof00brid, of course the whole book is a gem and well worth studying.

sure thanks for it

If you had a charge with just enough KE to reach the conductor, in practice, that charge will fail to reach the conductor. That charge would be radiating away energy as it comes in. There are good reasons why we define things to be moving infinitely slowly.

okay dont stress on my words before the addition of charge as my question is to what happens after it

@hyportnex  (on page 8)  the book talks about some kind of "boiler pressure"being exerted equal and opposite to the electric forces but there is no information available any where about that pressure can you provide some?

What Bridgman calls "boiler pressure" is the non-electrical force that holds the charges to stay on the surface: "The forces which prevent the charge from leaving the surface under this so-called ''boiler pressure" force must be described as non-electrical forces. This non-electrical force is exactly equal and opposite to the electrical force, and has no component longitudinal the surface, since the electrical force has no tangential component." Ultimately, the "boiler pressure" is actually found to be "electrical" in nature but in a quantum mechanical sense.

This question is similar to: What keeps electrons on a negatively-charged conductor from leaving?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also What force attracts electrons so that they cannot leave the conductor?.

Yes that's right, for a charged conductor the electric field outside the surface is directed such as to pull charge off the surface. The reason the charge doesn't leave the surface is to do with what is going on inside the surface. There are all the interactions with the atomic nuclei and things like that. For a large enough electric field, the charge does leave the surface: that is what is happening, for example, in an electrical spark or in the flow of ions off a liquid metal ion source. For more modest fields the attraction to the atoms in the conductor is enough to prevent charge (i.e. electrons in practice) from leaving. A potential energy curve taking this into account would show a dip at the surface. In an introductory treatment this dip is often ignored and one simply asserts that some sort of other force prevents the charge from leaving. This 'other force' is the total effect of all the constituents of the conductor.

so the charges on the conductor have zero potential and thats why theyre stable, or maybe potential less than the potential just outside kind of making a potential barrier? and then shouldnt this potential barrier be for all possible strengths of electric field? why does charge then shoot out at higher intensities?

They don't have zero potential, but they are in an atom-sized potential well. A high enough electric field will distort this well enough to let the electrons out. Look up "field emission" or "field ionization" for some related effects.

i have kind of made a proof of why it can't leave the conductor, would appreciate if you check it out  here is the link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/827153/372510
